# Can't subscribe a durable topic with Solace JMS

Tags: jms, subscribe, solace

I'd like to subscribe a durable topic using Solace JMS API. But when I start my application, it thrown below error:

[Context_3_ReactorThread] INFO com.solacesystems.jcsmp.impl.flow.BindRequestTask - Error Response (503) - Max clients exceeded for durable topic endpoint

I use the latest docker image of solace on centos 7. the image version is solace-pubsub-standard (9.1.0.201).

Below is my code:

```
@Bean
public SolConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
    SolConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new SolConnectionFactoryImpl();
    connectionFactory.setHost("10.69.94.182");
    connectionFactory.setUsername("default");
    connectionFactory.setPassword("default");
    connectionFactory.setVPN("default");
    connectionFactory.setDynamicDurables(true);
    return connectionFactory;
}


@Bean
public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory pubSubContainerFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory listenerContainerFactory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    listenerContainerFactory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    listenerContainerFactory.setPubSubDomain(true);
    listenerContainerFactory.setSubscriptionDurable(true);
    return listenerContainerFactory;
}



@JmsListener(destination = "com.schindler.ioee.gdcs.Callback", containerFactory = "pubSubContainerFactory")
public void processCallback(Message message) {
    /*message.getHeaders().entrySet().forEach(item -> log.info("{}:{}", item.getKey(), item.getValue()));*/
    log.info("[CONSUMER] topic={}, message={}", message.getHeaders().get("jms_destination"), message.getPayload());

}
```

I tried to set the max-bind-count for the topic endpoint to 1024, it also throw the above error.

Can any one provide some help. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was resolved after reading the document https://docs.solace.com/Solace-JMS-API/Creating-Durable-Topic-S.htm. 
I have 2 subscription, and I missed to add a subscription in the annotation. If the subscription name is missing, spring will use the default name "org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter" as the subscription name. According to the document, one session can't subscribe the same topic endpoint twice. So an error was thrown.

My finally consumer code looks like below:

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class MessageConsumer {

    @JmsListener(destination = "com.schindler.ioee.gdcs.Callback", containerFactory = "pubSubContainerFactory", subscription = "com.schindler.ioee.gdcs.Callback")
    public void processCallback(Message message) {
        // message.getHeaders().entrySet().forEach(item -> log.info("{}:{}", item.getKey(), item.getValue()));
        log.info("[CONSUMER] topic={}, message={}", message.getHeaders().get("jms_destination"), message.getPayload());

    }

    @JmsListener(destination = "com.schindler.ioee.gdcs.Symptom", containerFactory = "pubSubContainerFactory", subscription = "com.schindler.ioee.gdcs.Symptom")
    public void processSymptom(Message message) {
        // message.getHeaders().entrySet().forEach(item -> log.info("{}:{}", item.getKey(), item.getValue()));
        log.info("[CONSUMER] topic={}, message={}", message.getHeaders().get("jms_destination"), message.getPayload());

    }

    @JmsListener(destination = "com.schindler.ioee.gdcs.Equipment", containerFactory = "pubSubContainerFactory", subscription = "com.schindler.ioee.gdcs.Equipment")
    public void processEquipment(Message message) {
        // message.getHeaders().entrySet().forEach(item -> log.info("{}:{}", item.getKey(), item.getValue()));
        log.info("[CONSUMER] topic={}, message={}", message.getHeaders().get("jms_destination"), message.getPayload());

    }


    @JmsListener(destination = "t/cn/rtc/*/status", subscription = "sms_mqtt_subscription", containerFactory = "pubSubContainerFactory")
    public void processStatus(Message message) {
        // message.getHeaders().entrySet().forEach(item -> log.info("{}:{}", item.getKey(), item.getValue()));
        log.info("[CONSUMER] topic={}, message={}", message.getHeaders().get("jms_destination"), new String((byte[]) message.getPayload()));

    }
}
```